# Update HTTP Handler - Request Restrictions - Mapping Tab via Powershell or APPCMD

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, appcmd

In IIS 7.5, I am trying to update the request restrictions for the handler mappings. I know you can use appcmd or ps and edit the verbs or access, but I want to be able to run a command that will "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to: FILE".

I found this article in technet, which basically will allow me to edit everything except the tab that I need to change.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730969(v=ws.10).aspx

For example

```
appcmd set config /section:handlers /[name=' ImageCopyrightHandler '].verb:GET,HEAD
```

I've tried pretty much every command I can come up with but none of them seem to work.

[This is what I am trying to edit for each handler mapping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwfHX.jpg)

I'd hate to have to do each one manually, since it has to be done on 3 servers are there are 35 isapi module handers in each one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute you're looking for is [`resourceType`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add#005) with a value of `File`

Comment: You sir are awesome. For anyone interested here is the full string that I'm using for each module.  appcmd set config /section:handlers /[name='PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit'].resourceType:File

Comment: @ChrisTulumba Awesome. If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it "Accepted" on the left

Answer (score 0):

You sir are awesome.

For anyone interested here is the full string that I'm using for each module.

appcmd set config /section:handlers /[name='PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit'].resourceType:File